# How to add a custom corpora to local machine in nltk

Tags: python, nltk, nltk-trainer

I have a custom corpora that created with data which i need to do some classification. I have the dataset in a same format that movie_reviews corpora contains. According to nltk documentation i use following code to access to movie_reviews corpora. Is there anyway to add any custom corpora to nltk_data/corpora directory and access that corpora as the same way we access existing corpora.

```
    import nltk
    from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews

    documents = [(list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category)
         for category in movie_reviews.categories()
         for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you *could* hack the nltk to make your corpus look like a built-in nltk corpus, that's the wrong way to go about it. The `nltk` provides a rich collection of "corpus readers" that you can use to read your corpora from wherever you keep them, without moving them to the `nltk_data` directory or hacking the `nltk` source. The nltk's own corpora use the same corpus readers behind the scenes, so your reader will have all the methods and behavior of equivalent built-in corpora.

Let's see how the `movie_reviews` corpus is defined in `nltk/corpora/__init__.py`:

```
movie_reviews = LazyCorpusLoader(
    'movie_reviews', CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader,
    r'(?!\.).*\.txt', cat_pattern=r'(neg|pos)/.*',
    encoding='ascii')
```

You can ignore the `LazyCorpusLoader` part; it's for providing corpora that your program will most likely never use. The rest shows that the movie review corpus is read with a `CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader`, that its files all end in `.txt`, and that the reviews are sorted into categories through being in the subdirectories `pos` and `neg`. Finally, the corpus encoding is ascii. So define your own corpus like this (changing values as needed):

```
mycorpus = nltk.corpus.reader.CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader(
    r"/home/user/path/to/my_corpus",
    r'(?!\.).*\.txt', 
    cat_pattern=r'(neg|pos)/.*',
    encoding="ascii")
```

That's it; you can now call `mycorpus.words()`, `mycorpus.sents(categories="neg")`, etc., just as if this was a corpus provided by the nltk.

Answer (score 1):

First put the actual data from your new corpus into your `nltk_data/corpora/` directory. Then you have to edit the `__init__.py` file for `nltk.corpus`. You can find the path to this file by doing:

```
import nltk
print(nltk.corpus.__file__)
```

Open this file in a text editor and you will see that most of the file is creating `LazyCorpusLoader` objects and assigning them to global variables.

So for example, a section may look like:

```
....
verbnet = LazyCorpusLoader(
    'verbnet', VerbnetCorpusReader, r'(?!\.).*\.xml')
webtext = LazyCorpusLoader(
    'webtext', PlaintextCorpusReader, r'(?!README|\.).*\.txt', encoding='ISO-8859-2')
wordnet = LazyCorpusLoader(
    'wordnet', WordNetCorpusReader,
    LazyCorpusLoader('omw', CorpusReader, r'.*/wn-data-.*\.tab', encoding='utf8'))  
....
```

In order to add a new corpus you just have to add a new line to this file in the same format as the examples above. So if you have a corpus named `movie_reviews` and you have the data saved in `nltk_data/corpora/movie_reviews` then you would want to add a line like:

```
movie_reviews = LazyCorpusLoader('movie_reviews', .... )
```

Additional arguments for LazyCorpusLoader can be found in the docs [here](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.html#nltk.corpus.util.LazyCorpusLoader).

Then you just save this file and you should then be able to do:

```
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
```

Comment: And then, one day, you update NLTK and these changes will be wiped away without notice. It's safer to go with alexis' answer, really.

Comment: @bunji - Tried with alexis way. It's working. Thank for ur guide

Comment: @Janitha, glad to help. I guess I misinterpreted your request to access it "the same way we access existing corpora" as meaning it should be importable like existing corpora. my bad...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I had a bit of a problem with the solution provided and I find the easiet way that worked for me is to first create my folders and subfolder in the 'corpora' directory and then edit the **init**.py doc.

so in my case the corpus I created was vc and the subfolders were audio_them, audio_us, video_them, video_us

```
vc = LazyCorpusLoader(
    'vc', CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader,
    r'(?!\.).*\.txt', 
cat_pattern = r'(audio_them|audio_us|video_them|video_us)/.$
    encoding="ascii")
```